# Can i make the special price override the catalog price rules?

Tags: magento-1.7, ce-1.7.0.2

Is it possible to override the catalog price rules with the special price?

Answer (score 3):

I think you can achieve this by adding a new condition to the catalog rule: `Special Price  less than  0.01`. Just make sure that the `special_price` attribute can be used in catalog rules.